# org.springframework.data.repository always null into custom UserDetailManager

Tags: spring, spring-security, dependency-injection, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

In my project I've a DAO defined as a org.springframework.data.[repository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html)

```java
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "/user")
public interface SymtUserDAO extends CrudRepository<User, Long>{
...
```

It works fine in controllers by @Autowired (Dependency Injection):

```java
@Controller
public class ProveController {
  @Autowired
  private SymtUserDAO dao;
  ...
```

I need to use it in my custom [UserDetailsManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/provisioning/UserDetailsManager.html) but in here the dao is always null

```
public class SymtUserManager implements UserDetailsManager {
  @Autowired
  private SymtUserDAO dao;
```

I don't know if it matters but I instantiate my custom UserDetailManager in the [AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter.html)'s constructor

```java
/**
 * This class is used to configure how our authorization server (the "/oauth/token" endpoint) 
 * validates client credentials.
 */
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 100)
protected static class OAuth2Config extends
        AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter
{
....
   public OAuth2Config() throws Exception {
      UserDetailsService svc = new SymtUserManager(...
```

Why my working DAO (test passed in the controller) doesn't work ( it is always null) in the UserDetailsManager? what I have to do to use the DAO ( repository ) also into the UserDetailsManager?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631791/cannot-get-userdetailsmanager-injected-with-spring-boot-and-java-based-configura

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: zeroflagL is right. I updated answer according to comments.

Your SymtUserManager is not s spring bean. Therefore it's not created and handeled by Spring bean container. Therefore spring can't inject dependency there.

You can autowire it into OAuth2Config constructor and pass it as constructor parameter to SymtUserManager:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 100)
protected static class OAuth2Config extends
    AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter
{
    private SymtUserDAO dao;

    @Autowire
    public OAuth2Config(SymtUserDAO dao) throws Exception {
         UserDetailsService svc = new SymtUserManager(dao, ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint but even in OAuth2Config the @Autowired SymtUserDAO dao; is null in the constructor so even if I change the SymtUserManager constroctur it isn't valid.

Comment: When you use field injection then `dao` will be always be null in the constructor.

Comment: If you need dao in your constructor, annotate constructor with @Autowired

Comment: The answer and comments drive me in the right direction and I found a way to refactor my classes and solve the problem.